# Is the @Injectable decorator basically the angular 2 equivalent of @Component or @Autowired in Spring?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, frontend, angular-fullstack

Does `@Injectable` mean

> "allow injection of **whatever** into the class which the decorator is above"

Or

> Does it mean "allow me to inject this class (which the decorator is above) into '**wherever**' in the application"?

Answer (score 3):

`@Injectable` is just a marker that tells to angular engine that the class is available to be created by Injectors.  At runtime angular tells to Injectors to read all the `@Injectable` classes and instantiate them and make them available to be injected to the classes that reference them.

For example lets suppose that there is a service in angular called `UserService` and you need to use that service in a component called `RegistrationComponent`.

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {

     saverUser(User user)
     .....
     }
```

Then in the `RegistrationComponent` constructor declare an input parameter that reference to `UserService`, it tells to angular that UserService should be injected to `RegistrationComponent`, of course previously the `@Injectable` marker should be declared in `UserService`

RegistrationComponent.ts

```
export class RegistrationComponent 

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }
```

In the Spring context the `@Component` plays a similar job than `@Injectable` of course there are many difference between them in the implementation, but both of them play a similar role.  `@Component` is an annotation that tells to Spring that some specific class has to be considered a candidate for auto-detection and that class can lives in the Spring Container.  The components (beans) living in the Spring Container can be injected to other classes.

`@Autowired` is not the same as `@Component`. `@Autowired` means that an specific class member should be provided or injected by Spring DI container.

For more information please see the following links:

[Angular Dependency Injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection)

[@Autowired Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html)

[@Component Spring Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html)

Comment: I think another differnce is, that @Injectable classes are not created per se, just if they are injected in another class.